# Inserting file into SQL server without BULK statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I insert an image (using a query) into SQL server without using the BULK statement.

I need to achieve this as I do not have permission to use BULK on my (university) server.

Answer (score 1):

Your should store image in a folder in the application namely **Uplaods** and store its relative path is the database in a field.

When retrieving retrieve Url of the file and do whatever is business logic for it.

Comment: This is better way.It is good to store image on File server than database server.

Comment: How would I display it in ASP.net if it was stored as a path

Comment: it is not a good approach to store file bytes in the database

Comment: you can store relative path like "~/Uplads/file.doc" for example, while retreiving get this path from datbase and create its absolut path : Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/file.doc"), this will give you its exact path and you can do whatever you want to do with file either delete, download it to user or whatever

Comment: How would you display it in asp.net?  With an html <img> tag.

Comment: make img tag like this:
<img id="myImg" runat="server" />
from codebehind: myImg.src = "~/Uploads/Image.jpg";
or  myImg.src = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Image.jpg");